# MYSQL - How to UPDATE after SELECT from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-select-db

i want to UPDATE the a column after i SELECT a table

```
SELECT id_copies, id_shop, id_dvd 
FROM dvd_copies
WHERE id_dvd = '001-192.168.1.103-6' AND id_shop='002'
ORDER BY id_copies DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

i got just 2 rows that i want to be updated
how can i UPDATE these rows?

Comment: What you are asking for is not posible with mysql. You would need some programming language to handle the query results and run the UPDATE queries.

Comment: use stored procedure.

Comment: @orangehippo it is possible, please see the answer by vhu below

Comment: It looks like I was half slept, lol ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do the following:

```
UPDATE dvd_copies
SET your_column_to_update ='your value'
WHERE id_dvd = '001-192.168.1.103-6' AND id_toko='002'
ORDER BY id_copies DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: This was very useful - i just forget that i can use LIMIT option in update query. That with order by keyword can complete relatively complex task with easy :) Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can use a nested select in your update query,note it will update your rows with same value 
not with a different value for each row

```
UPDATE dvd_copies 
SET your_column_to_update ='your value'
WHERE id_copies IN(
    SELECT t.id_copies FROM 
    (SELECT id_copies
        FROM dvd_copies 
        WHERE id_dvd = '001-192.168.1.103-6' AND id_toko='002'
        ORDER BY id_copies DESC LIMIT 2
    ) t
)
```